# How to change style of an element in code behind .net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I change the classes/Style of a div in my controller? I tried using `runat` but it didnt work. here is an example

```
<div id="MainDiv" class="flex justify-between items-center">
     <a>Done</a>
 </div>
```

How can i add a `bg-red-300` class to `MainDiv` if certain conditions apply and if not add a `bg-green-300` class instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way,you could judge the data in client side like below:

```
@model Test
<div id="MainDiv" class="flex justify-between items-center @(Model.IsDone=="Yes"?"bg-red-300":"bg-green-300")">
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Test()
    {
        IsDone=="Yes"
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

The second way,you could use ViewData to store the class and judge in the server side:

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    var styleClass = ViewData["Style"];
}

<div id="MainDiv" class="flex justify-between items-center @styleClass">
    <a>Done</a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if(YourCondition)
    {
        ViewData["Style"] = "bg-red-300";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewData["Style"] = "bg-green-300";
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you have a Model backing your view, with some C# property of a boolean type that will define if this field is valid, or not, let's call it `Valid`. Usually such validation is based on some more complex logic so I assume you have something like that.

You could edit the style inline, or replace whole blocks of HTML view depending on how much of the view you need to change based on this model value.

Both approaches are documented with example fiddle for you to eventually play with it.
I see you're using tailwindcss, so I have simply copied this style.

```cs
using System;

namespace ExampleApp
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        public bool Valid { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Example Controller:

```cs
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ExampleApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new SampleViewModel();
            model.Valid = false;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

And example view:

```html
@model ExampleApp.SampleViewModel
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Css based on Model</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .bg-red-300 {
            background-color: #feb2b2;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="MainDiv" class="flex justify-between items-center">
        <span>Done</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Whole block change -->
    @if (Model.Valid)
    {
    <div id="MainDiv" class="flex justify-between items-center">
        <span>Done</span>
    </div>
    }
    else
    {
    <div id="MainDiv" class="flex justify-between items-center bg-red-300">
        <span>Done</span>
    </div>
    }

    <!-- inline style change -->

    <div id="MainDiv2" class="flex justify-between items-center @(Model.Valid ? "" : " bg-red-300")">
        <span>Done</span>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have posted a simple .net fiddle for you to check live:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/h7JTR2